# Cannot remove the last image file of a collection in carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, carrierwave

I want to selectively remove the uploaded images as a solution provided at [issue#1704](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1704).
Everything works fine except that when I want to delete the last image in my collection It does not assign the `images` value to `[]` the below is the debugging mode that I tested the procedure manually and deliberately assigned the `images` to `[]` but the model persists in maintaining its previous value!!

I guess you have to open the below image in new tab and zoom in to see details :D

[image]

The code is as following:
[image]

The database schema:

```
create_table "furniture_types", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.text     "comment",         limit: 65535
  t.datetime "created_at",                                    null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                                    null: false
  t.json     "images"
  t.boolean  "is_inside_type",                default: false
  t.boolean  "is_outside_type",               default: false
end
```

#### How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned at [the issue](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/2141#issuecomment-287530290) that I've opened, the CarrierWave deliberately rejects empty or `nil` values for the uploader columns, so I have come up with a hack to bypass the restriction, and it works well!

```
@instance.write_attribute(:images, nil)
```